# Flexslider viewport height unresponsive on resize

Tags: jquery, height, responsive-design, flexslider

I'm trying to use Flexslider with text-based content on each slide, which means that the vertical heights of the slides and viewport need to alter dynamically depending on the width of the window.

On load, Flexslider initialises, and some subsequent jQuery makes all slides the same height as the viewport and centres the contents vertically within each slide. If you don't resize the browser, this is fine. However, if you do, there are a couple of issues:

- If you change the window size, the height of the viewport was already set on load, and doesn't alter, so shrinking the window makes the text overflow and vanish, and expanding it makes the slide look very blank.
- Bizarrely, if you're resizing the window *as the page loads*, then the viewport assumes a fairly large height.

There's also another issue which might be related to this:
 * On load, I briefly see a multicoloured mess as Flexslider initialises.

My code looks like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/link/to/flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var verticalCenterer = function () {
            $(this).css('margin-top', ($(this).parent().height()-($(this).outerHeight()))/2);
        };

    var carouselInit = function() {
        var carouselHeight = $('.flex-viewport').innerHeight();
        $('.slides li').css('height',carouselHeight);
        $('p').each(function()
            {
            $(this).css('margin-top', ($(this).parent().height()-($(this).outerHeight()))/2);
            }
        );
        }

    $(window).load(function() {
      $('.carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        slideshowSpeed: 2000,
        animationSpeed: 500,
        directionNav: false,
        pausePlay: true,
        pauseText: '',
        playText: '',
        start: carouselInit
      });
       alert('Wait a moment');
    });

    $(window).resize(carouselInit);

    </script>

<div class="carousel">
    <ul class="slides">
    <li style="background: #ff9999;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 4; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 5; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 6; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 7; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 8; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 9; <strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 10</strong>; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 11; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 12; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 13; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 14; <strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 15</strong>.</p>
    </li>
    <li style="background: #9999ff;">
        <p>A shorter one</p>
    </li>
    <li style="background: #99ff99;">
        <p>Test text test text Test text test text Test text test text Test text test text Test text test text Test text test text Test text test text Test text test text</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I've also made [an example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FMrL/3/):

- Both the slide markup and the page-specific JavaScript is in the HTML.
- The JavaScript contains the latest minified Flexslider code.
- I've put in an alert which runs on load to freeze the multi-slide mess.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just comment the following:

```
....
//$(window).resize(carouselInit);

        </script>

<div class="carousel">
....
```

comment $(window).resize(carouselInt) in your code before closing script tag.
Check the following working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/saidbakr/6FMrL/9/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by changing the viewport size and slide width on every browser resize with the following code:

```
  $(window).on('resize', function () {

        if ($('.flexslider').length > 0) {

            $('.flexslider').each(function () {

                $(this).find('.flex-viewport').css('height', 'auto');

                $(this).find('>.slides').each(function () {
                    let height = $(this).css('height');
                    $(this).find('> li').css('width', height);
                });

            });
        }
    });
```